# ASP.NET Core 2.0 InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package '<assemblyname>'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages project. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

I have added one of our in-house assemblies to the project (it contains common definitions, types and functions etc). The project compiles but when I attempt to run it I get the following error.

[image]

Here is my .csproj file

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Version>2018.3.12.6</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="JWT" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-setversion" Version="*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Common">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Here's my Visual Studio 2017 project showing the assembly in the project.

[image]

Googling the error doesn't provide much useful information.

How do I add a reference to a custom assembly in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages project?

Comment: Did you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279561/asp-net-core-2-cannot-find-compilation-library-location-for-package-projectname ?

Comment: Yes I saw that post. The accepted answer is MVC related. I'm not using MVC. My project is a Razor Pages project.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the same issue by installing `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel`, version 2.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem has been posted here https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/2981

See the top comment (by tuespetre) and then the update just further down (also by tuespetre). This worked for me.